# Python "List" object is not callable

Tags: python

I'm writing a program that looks through CSVs in a directory and appends the contents of each CSV to a list. Here's a snippet of the offending code:

```
import glob
import re 

c = glob.glob("*.csv")
print c
archive = []

for element in c:
    look = open(element, "r").read()
    open = re.split("\n+", look)

    for n in open:
        n = re.split(",", n)[0]
        archive.append(n)
```

However, when I run this script, I get a `TypeError: 'list' object is not callable`. Can somebody please explain what's going on?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I think it's because you redefine `open` as a list and call it in the next loop iteration.
Just give the list another name.

Note that strings have a `split()` method for when you don't need a regex.

Answer (score 5):

*The fact that `open` is a builtin function is irrelevant. It could have been a function defined in the same module.*

The basic problem is that the same name was used to refer to two different objects (a function and a list), both of which were needed again. When the first object was needed again, the name referred to the second object. Result: splat. The golden rule is: don't re-use names unthinkingly.

Answer (score 2):

The gold rule is: never use the name of a builtin thing for your variables!

It's a matter of aliasing, just don't call the list `open`..

Answer (score 2):

Agree with previous answers: never call a variable `open` or any other [builtin](http://docs.python.org/library/functions.html).

You may be interested int the Python [csv module](http://docs.python.org/library/csv.html), which will correctly parse csv files that `re.split(',', line)` won't.

Also, you can use the file object as a line-by-line iterator like so:

```
for line in open('data.csv'):
    do_something(line)
```